# How to reverse proxy with Docker and Ubuntu Tutorial

Tags: docker, npm, reverse-proxy

I am trying to reproduce [this git repository](https://github.com/canonical-web-and-design/tutorials.ubuntu.com) with a few tutorial-based lecture notes. This website is basically docker container with npm and yarn technology. It works fine within my network say 10.35.34.35:8000. But, if I use reverse proxy and give it in public say [www.abc.xyz.com/tutorial](http://www.abc.xyz.com/tutorial), it is not working. The error is due to an incorrect path that is not recognized by the docker to send the request back.

When the index.html `<base href="/">` is changed to `<base href="tutorial/">` it is reaching the index.html page properly, but the tutorial elements are not mapped back again.
I get the following error:
https://abc.xyz.com/tutorial/src/tutorial.html 404 (Not Found)

I have tried many possibilities to rectify this error, by changing each elements' absolute path, but none worked efficiently. Could someone suggest an efficient solution to resolve this?

To Reproduce, please follow the following instructions

1. Download docker in machine
2. Download the following code from github: https://github.com/canonical-web-and-design/tutorials.ubuntu.com
3. Run the command  `./run serve` inside the downloaded folder
4. Reverse proxy on apache config as follows

`ProxyPass /tutorials http://10.35.34.35:8000`

`ProxyPassReverse /tutorials https://10.35.34.35:8000`

5. Restart apache

Comment: Checkout nginx and url rewriting. You can do this much better with K3D using Kubernetes' ingress controllers.

Comment: My main server works on apache

Comment: With no code details it's really hard to tell what's going on here; can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  Docker doesn't generally deal with anything above the TCP layer; it wouldn't inspect or change URL paths on its own.

Comment: Example is simple:
https://github.com/canonical-web-and-design/tutorials.ubuntu.com
This website has a script called run
If we run the command, ./run serve, it creates a website very well.
Now, we can use my machine IP to reach from any machine in my network

Reverse proxy was done as follows:
ProxyPass /tutorials HTTP://10.35.34.35:8000
ProxyPassReverse /tutorials https://10.35.34.35:8000